# Undefined reference to function - Learning C

Tags: c

I'm learning C by translating some of the things I have done in Python to C. I have tried to look online as much as I can before coming here but it seems really difficult to find answers to what I'm looking for.

What follows is my (so-far) translation of the Miller-Rabin test for a number's primality.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

_Bool prime(long long n);

int main() {
    int i = 6;
    for (i; i < 9; i++) {
        if (prime(i)) {
            printf("%i\n", prime(i));
        }
    }
}

_Bool prime(long long n) {
    int s = 0;
    int r = 0;
    int a_index = 0;
    // printf("the value of a_index when initialised is: %d\n", a_index);
    // printf("the value of s when initialised is: %d\n", s);
    int *a_list;
    _Bool is_prime = 1;
    _Bool composite_part_a = 1;
    _Bool composite_part_b = 1;
    long long d = n - 1;
    while (d % 2 == 0) {
        s++;
        d = d / 2;
    }

    if (4759123141 <= n && n < 2152302898747) {
        // malloc
        a_list[0] = 2;
        a_list[1] = 3;
        a_list[2] = 5;
        a_list[3] = 7;
        a_list[4] = 11;
    }
    else if (9080191 <= n && n < 4759123141) {
        // malloc
        a_list[0] = 2;
        a_list[1] = 7;
        a_list[2] = 61;
    }
    else if (1373653 <= n && n < 9080191) {
        // malloc
        a_list[0] = 31;
        a_list[1] = 73;
    }           
    else if (4 <= n && n < 1373653) {
        a_list = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
        a_list[0] = 2;
        a_list[1] = 3;
        printf("the value of a_list[0] upon its first assignment is: %d\n", a_list[0]);
        // printf("the first element of a_list is: %d\n", a_list[0]);
        // printf("the second element of a_list is: %d\n", a_list[1]);
    }
    else if (n == 3 | n == 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (n % 2 == 0 | n == 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    printf("the value of a_list[0] over here is: %d\n", a_list[0]);
    // printf("%d\n", a_list[1]);  
    for (a_index; a_index < sizeof(a_list) / sizeof(int); a_index++) {
        printf("test");
        if ((long long)pow(a_index[a_list], d) % n != 1) {
            composite_part_a = 1;
        }
        else {
            composite_part_a = 0;
        }


        // printf("the value of r is: %d\n", r);
        // printf("the value of s is: %d\n", s);
        for (r; r < s; r++) {
            printf("%lld\n", (int)pow(a_list[a_index], exp2(r) * d) % n);
            if ((long long)pow(a_index[a_list], exp2(r) * d) % n != -1) {
                composite_part_b = 1;
            }
            else {
                composite_part_b = 0;
                break;
            }
            }

        if (composite_part_a && composite_part_b) {
            return 0;
        }
        }

    return is_prime;
    }
```

The trouble with learning C is there isn't much good literature for pure beginners, outside of what I hear about K&R but that's in the mail and I can't get my hands on it right now. The program returns these errors:

```
3.c: In function ‘prime’:
3.c:52:26: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]
/tmp/ccGQnk9T.o: In function `prime':
3.c:(.text+0x272): undefined reference to `pow'
3.c:(.text+0x2b9): undefined reference to `exp2'
3.c:(.text+0x2db): undefined reference to `pow'
3.c:(.text+0x30b): undefined reference to `exp2'
3.c:(.text+0x32d): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

First off, haven't I included  to introduce pow and else? I know it's not proper to ask two questions and my main question is about pow and exp2, but if you do have a suggestion about the malloc as well feel free to include it.

Comment: It is not your program executable, it is the `gcc` compiler (and linker) which returns the "undefined reference" errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to *link* with the math library as well, it's not included by default.

Something like the following command:

```
$ gcc 3.c -lm
```

Notice the `-lm` argument... It tells the linker to add a library (the `-l` part) and the name of the library (the `m` part).

Comment: Legend. I assume I will have to do this with most libraries?

Comment: But you really want to get all the warnings and debugging information from the compiler, so use  `gcc -Wall -g 3.c -lm -o prog3` to compile, and learn to use `gdb prog3` to debug your program.

Comment: @nebffa If it's a library that's not linked with by default (which is none except the pure standard C library) then yes. Even though the math library is part of the standard it's not linked with by default, probably mostly because of historic reasons now days.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - bear in mind -wall doesnt enable all warnings!   There are many more warnings you need to produce better code (-wextra etc etc).

Comment: I know that `-Wall` don't give all warnings, but it is the option I suggest to newbies.

Comment: @Neil What are the other 'warning enablers'? Are they too complex to be using right now? Note: I am fairly experienced in Python by this point and am learning C to teach me what is really going on with the computer. I'm leaning on the side of using these extra warnings unless you guys caution me against it.

Comment: @nebffa For a complete reference on all public warning options of GCC see their [reference documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options). However `-Wall` is usually enough to begin with, but other common arguments are `-pedantic` and possible `-Wextra`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I would say -Wall is not enough and can hide things you should be fixing.  We use -Wextra here but can't agree on others so add them depending on the project.  -Werror is also a good one so you have to fix the warnings as you go on.  Before this, we had a project with so many warnings you couldn't see what the real problems were.

Answer (score 3):

Math functions are part of `libm`. Link them when you compile with `-lm`.

Comment: How exactly would you do this?

Comment: If you are using gcc then: `gcc file.c -o file -lm`

Answer (score 1):

3.c:52:26: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]

Is caused by a missing include, malloc() is defined in stdlib.h so need to include that.

3.c:(.text+0x272): undefined reference to `pow' (and the rest)

Is caused by a missing link to libm. Most (if not all) methods in math.h are not in standard libc that always gets linked but in libm instead.

How to link differs between compiler, but for gcc (and many other unix compilers):

gcc 3.c -o 3 -lm

Where "-lm" tells gcc to link libm.

Comment: hmmm... I now realise the reason for asking one question only. You can only accept an answer to one of the questions. I would select this as correct if it weren't for me already saying the <math.h> was the main part. But this is extremely clear, thankyou very much for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `<stdlib.h>` for malloc and free.

For the math stuff to work you have to link it,
    `gcc 3.c -lm`
Where `-l` is the library flag and m is tell it to use the math library

Also you need to move the definition of prime to above main, things need to be declared in order.

Since you are just starting here are some other helpful flags for the compiler

`-g` this will give better debugging when using valgrind or gdb.

`-o` lets you define the compiled file name eg: `gcc 3.c -o 3` will create `./3` instead of `./a.out`